# Unable to create exe for EEL python Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, eel

I have below python EEL folder structure

```
Main:
  app.py
  web:
     src:
        asset:
               
               images:
                    image.jpg
               style :
                     style.js
        component:
                index.html
      static:
          Input :
                 file1.csv
                 file2.csv
```

My python code is in App.py and HTML code is in index.html. I am trying to create exe using below code

```
python.exe -m eel --onefile  "C:\Projects\HR Digital Twin\Python Ui\ups_modified\ups_modified\main\src\component\"  app.py
```

I am unable to get the clean exe . I want to understand what is the right way to create exe when you have files spread across different folders. Could you please help me . Posting the error here after exe is created

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main_graphs.py", line 1, in
>    File "", line 1007, in
> _find_and_load   File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 680, in *load_unlocked   File
> "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
>
> File "eel_*init**.py", line 15, in    File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File
> "", line 680, in _load_unlocked   File
> "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
> File "bottle.py", line 73, in  AttributeError: 'NoneType'
> object has no attribute 'write'